# Where to find list of colors for vim?

Tags: vim

I am trying to customize my `cursorline` by doing something like this:

```
:highlight CursorLine ctermfg=White ctermbg=21 cterm=bold
```

Is there a place that shows what the actual color options are? For example, it looks like mine has thousands of options (ctermbg=2121 is different than ctermbg=2122, etc.), or is there a way to enter in a hex code instead, such as: `ctermbg=#EEEEEE` ?

Where can I find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your underlying terminal is truly capable of TrueColor, you can just say to Vim: `:set termguicolors`. Then all `ctermXX` will be ignored and `guiXX` will be used instead even in console Vim.

However, if your terminal is not capable of TrueColor then "those color numbers" are in fact just "palette indexes", and their meaning depends on your terminal setup. For standard "xterm" and such you can google for appropriate tables. There are quite a few webpages out there.